# what is the difference between /. and /; in mathematica?

Tags: syntax

What is the difference between /. and /; in Wolfram Mathematica 
How would you apply them both and what situations are each of them appropriate to use?

Comment: I would recommend typing these abbreviations into the documentation browser and reading what comes up first. You'll see you'll get referred to `ReplaceAll` and `Condition`, which are the functions that `/.` and `/;` are abbreviations for. You can find out about other cryptic Wolfram symbols this way as well: `;`, `/@`, `@@` etc.

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/25616#25616